# How to pause and resume a python script

Tags: python, execution, resume, pause

First of all I am not a python specialist.
I am currently working on a machine learning issue where I must run scripts that could take days to end. So to make it easier for me, I am looking for a method that could pause the execution, save the execution state in a file or something.

The goal is to be able to interrupt the script, save the execution state, do something else even maybe power down the computer. Then come back load the execution state and run the program without starting over from the beginning.
I don't know if it is something possible, but it would make things a lot easier for me.
Thank you for your help

Comment: I never hear if there is method for stoping running code - if you don't do this in code and save it in file. Maybe if you "hibernate" system then it may keep state and restart it after restart hibernated system. But this stops all functions in system, not only your script. Maybe if you would run it in some Virtual Machine (like VirtualBox) then you would hibernate only this machine.

Comment: maybe if you need run it many days then run it on some external server - ie. [Google CoLab](https://colab.research.google.com/), it can run all time and it can use GPU or TPU to make it faster. [Tensorflow with GPU](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb)

Comment: Okay, if you're running linux / unix / macos, you can just pause the process with CTRL-Z (in the program) or kill -STOP (yes -STOP pauses the program) (the state will still be in ram, but if you have SWAP, it will probably be paged away)

Comment: @python_user Do you know if sklearn has this kind of checkpoint feature?

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1, save model sate to disk

Okay, so if you want to save the machine learning algo's state to disk, this is going to depend on which library you are using (but basically, just save the state to disk at each epoch, when you need to pause stop the process, and when you resume, take the latest save).

- For `sklearn` there is a tutorial on how to do this : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html
- For `pytorch`, you can use `torch.save` and `torch.load`
- In general, in python, you may be able to use the `pickle` module to save whatever variables to a file. This is less stable than library-specific methods above, so use those instead if you can.
- . . .

### Method 2, pause the process

If you do not really need to save the state to disk, and you are running Linux / Unix / MacOS, you can just *pause the process*

- if you are in the terminal, it can be paused with `CTRL-Z`, and resumed later with the command `fg`
- otherwise you can use `kill -STOP $YOUR_PROCESS_PID`  to pause the process (yep `STOP` *pauses* the process, *it doesn’t terminate it*, I know this is confusing), and `kill -CONT $YOUR_PROCESS_PID` to restart it

the problem with this method, is that the state stays in RAM (but it will be paged out to swap if you have it), so **it will not persist across reboots, use the first method if you need that**

Comment: more info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/suspend-resume-single-process-to-from-disk